# REST POST duplicate list item

Tags: rest

I have a REST resource which contains a list of items.

e.g.: GET http://myurl/rest/items

The items do not have an id at the moment. (but that doesn't really matter)
The list should not contain duplicates. Duplicates are determined based on the properties of an item.
When a new item is created, it should be added to the top of the list. When the item already exists, it should be moved to the top of the list.

We implemented this now by using a post which returns a 201 when the item is new. It can just be added to the top of the list. When the item already exists, the item is moved to the top of the list and we return a [205 RESET CONTENT](http://httpstatus.es/205).
This is an indication to the frontend that it needs to refresh the item list.

This seemed like a good solution as it is easy to understand, altough I am not sure if it is the most 'restful' solution? Also, I am not sure if this is a correct usage of the 205 http code?

If there are any other suggestions, I would like to hear them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your approach interesting and RESTful since you leverage HTTP status codes to notify the client of different use cases. The intent is to tell the client to clear the content from the form or to refresh the UI. Here is the spec:

> The server has fulfilled the request and the user agent SHOULD reset the 
>   document view which caused the request to be sent. This response is 
>   primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place via user
>   input, followed by a clearing of the form in which the input is given
>   so that the user can easily initiate another input action.

I read that status code `205` mainly focuses form resetting forms. For example, to enter a series of records in succession: fill a form, send data, the server tells the Web UI to reset the form to send something else within the same form and so on. It's something assumed to be supported by browsers but they actually don't support this! In fact, the code is really uncommon.

But, in our case, I find that this matches your need and it's much more RESTful.

Another approach could be simply to use a status code `200` to tell to the client that the request is successful but no addition occurs unlike with a status code `201`. With a status code `200`, you implicitely know that the item was moved to the top of the list, so you need to refresh the list.

Here is an interesting post of status codes 204 and 205: https://benramsey.com/blog/2008/05/http-status-204-no-content-and-205-reset-content/.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry